# Почему в диалоговом окне , половина окна черная ?

Tags: c#, окно

Собственно, с самого написания программы, постоянно при запуске и выборе какого-то действия (где выскакивает диаг. окно) черный низ у окна, что это и как убрать у всех окон ЭТО?[image: Вокруг кнопок]

Comment: А само окно ваше?

Comment: Да, мое. Вся программа моя. 
Не понимаю с чем связанна эта чернота...

Comment: А если перегрузить компьютер?

Comment: Что? Ты о чем? Зачем перегружать его?   
Это не работает.

Comment: Похоже на нехватку видео или оперативной памяти. Не на виртуалке урезанной запускаете?

Comment: Нее, обычный вижуал 10 C#. Памяти 8гб оперативки. 
Странно , завтра протестирую на других пк тогда